# Access Amazon Alexa Console console.log() content

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, console.log

I'm using the online based [Amazon Alexa Console](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/) *test suite* and [AWS Lambda](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home) for the development of an Alexa skill. How to access the content of `console.log('STATE: ' + stateAbbreviation)`?

Lambda Function Code:

```
function getSmallImage(stateAbbreviation) {
  console.log('STATE: ' + stateAbbreviation);
  return getImageUrl(400, 720, stateAbbreviation);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CloudWatch** is the one which you are looking for.

Each time when a Lambda code is executed in response to an event, it writes a log entry into the log group associated with a Lambda function, which is `/aws/lambda/<function name>`. You can access this log entry using CloudWatch.

To access CloudWatch:

1. Goto the **Monitoring** tab of the Lambda function.
2. Then click on **View logs in CloudWatch**.

[image: Lambda function]

3. Select the latest stream to view the most recent log entries.

---

If you are under development and is using the in-line code editor of Lambda function, you can make use of **Test** feature to create a test event. In case of Alexa, you can create test events with the request JSON of Alexa. And when you fire a test event the Lambda function gets executed and the logs will be displayed right inside **Execution Results** tab of the code editor.